# Could there be any reserved/special variables for ajax?

Tags: ajax, apache, post

I came across a really strange error that I have no idea what is going on.

I am makign a POST ajax call with one variable called `password` as follows.

JavaScript

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/test.php',
    data : {
        password : '123\''
    },
    dataType: 'text'
})
.done(function (response) {
    console.debug('success');
})
.fail(function (err,textStatus,errorThrown) {
    console.debug('fail');
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

$password = $_POST['password'];
echo $password;

?>
```

This fails with a 403 Forbidden error. I assume this is because the variable `password` contains an unencoded single quote and $.ajax uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default. However, if I change the name of the variable to something else, e.g. `text`, then the error does not occur.

I tested this on both XAMPP on Linux and on my production server (which I rent from Namecheap.com). The error only happens in the latter. Both of the servers are using Apache.

So I thought that the variable name has some significance, but I have not heard any ways to enforce such a restriction on JavaScript variable names through server configurations. Or maybe it is done by something else. What is happening here? Should I stop bothering about this and choose a different variable name?

Comment: That sounds like a broken security filter (for incoming requests) on one of the servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a SQL injection prevention filter sitting in front of or installed as a module in Apache. Check your `.htaccess` files to make sure you don't have anything there, then talk to your hosting provider about it.

Answer (score 0):

Not "for AJAX", no, but possibly for whatever app you're posting to. Perhaps you have a global authentication layer that attempts to recognize a `username` / `password` pair on any page (which is a bad idea), or maybe, as Dark Falcon says, you have something installed at the webserver level. Reading the server error logs would be helpful, here.